# Autohotkey foreign language accents

Tags: autohotkey, diacritics

I'm trying to create an easy ahk script for sending letters with accent marks when typing in different languages.

I know I can use `!a::Send {U+00E0}` to send à, but is there an easy way to say "If I enter a capital a, send À? I thought I'd be able to use `!+a::Send {U+00C0}` but that doesn't seem to work (and also seems a bit more complicated than it should be)

Comment: Both `!a::Send {U+00E0}` (à) and `!+a::Send {U+00C0}` (À) work fine for me. I copied and pasted your code and used it to make the letters. What exactly happens when you try it?

Comment: Weird, it seems to work fine here, À, however in notepad++ it wasn't working, that shouldn't be too much of a problem though.

Comment: Another option may be the use of hotstrings. I can post that as an answer if you'd like to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Eabryt,

The way I addressed this in AutoHotKey is like this:

```
;===== SPECIAL CHARACTERS FOR US KEYBOARD DRIVER (NOT US INTERNATIONAL) =======
:?C*:`` :: ; Turn `{Space} into a neutral `, else ` will be used in next vowel.
    Send, ``{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:``a::à
:?C*:``i::ì
:?C*:``e::è
:?C*:``o::ò
:?C*:``u::ù
:?C*:``A::À
:?C*:``I::Ì
:?C*:``E::È
:?C*:``O::Ò
:?C*:``U::Ù

:?C*:^ :: ; Turn ^{Space} into neutral ^, else ^ will be used in next vowel.
    Send, {^}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:^a::â
:?C*:^i::î
:?C*:^e::ê
:?C*:^o::ô
:?C*:^u::û
:?C*:^A::Â
:?C*:^I::Î
:?C*:^E::Ê
:?C*:^O::Ô
:?C*:^U::Û

:?C*:`" :: ; Turn "{Space} into neutral ", else " will be used in next vowel.
    Send, +{'}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:`'a::ä ; I used 'because I use the Umlaut's much more often than the accent aigu
:?C*:`;a::ä
:?C*:`'i::ï
:?C*:`;i::ï
:?C*:`'e::ë
:?C*:`;e::ë
:?C*:`'o::ö
:?C*:`;o::ö
:?C*:`'u::ü
:?C*:`;u::ü
:?C*:`'A::Ä
:?C*:`'I::Ï
:?C*:`'E::Ë
:?C*:`'O::Ö
:?C*:`'U::Ü

:?C*:' :: ; Turn '{Space} into neutral ', else ' will be used in next vowel.
    Send, {'}{Space}{BackSpace}
Return

:?C*:`"a::á
:?C*:`"i::í
:?C*:`"e::é
:?C*:`"o::ó
:?C*:`"u::ú
:?C*:`"A::Á
:?C*:`"I::Í
:?C*:`"E::É
:?C*:`"O::Ó
:?C*:`"U::Ú

:?C*:`'c::ç
:?C*:`'C::Ç
:?C*:ss]::ß
:?C*:sss::ß
:?C*:ae]::æ
:?C*:AE]::Æ
:?C*:oe]::œ
:?C*:OE]::Œ
```

I use the Umlauts far more often than the accent aigu, therefore I (personally) swapped the use of the "and ' on my US International Keyboard. If this is too confusing, then just swap:

```
:?C*:`'a::ä    with    :?C*:`"a::ä
```

and

```
:?C*:`"a::á    with    :?C*:`'a::á
```

At the end are some special characters. I use the <kbd>]</kbd> as the end sign for these special characters as it is close to the <kbd>[Enter]</kbd> key.